# Are Clifford connections even?

Tags: clifford-algebras

I am currently reading the book [Heat Kernels and Dirac Operators](https://link.springer.com/book/9783540200628). I think that all Clifford connection should be even such that the associated Dirac operators are odd. (Dirac operators are defined to be odd in definition $3.36$.) It is not clear to me that this a consequence of the definition of Clifford connections (see below). Did they forget to make this part of definition?

> Definition $3.32$. A Clifford module $E$ on an even-dimensional Riemannian
> manifold $M$ is a $\mathbb{Z}_2$-graded bundle $E$ on $M$ with a graded action
> of the bundle of algebras $C(M)$ on it, which we write as follows:
> $$(a, s)\mapsto c(a)s,$$where $a\in\Gamma(M, C(M))$ and $s\in\Gamma(M, E)$.
>
> Definition $3.39$. If $\nabla^E$ is a connection on a Clifford module $E$, we say
> that $\nabla^E$ is a Clifford connection if for any $X,Y\in\Gamma(M, TM)$,
> $$[\nabla_X^E, c(Y)] = c(\nabla_XY).$$
> In this formula, $\nabla$ is the Levi-Civita covariant derivative.